# Printing values from a loop in PHP

Tags: php

Below is a loop I have in my code. Once when the starting and ending values are a zero the loop prints a value zero (0). But what I need to do here is when the starting and ending value is zero, it should print nothing. Can someone please tell me how to change the approach?

```
while ($recQ = mysqli_fetch_array($runx))
{
   for($ii=$recQ['start']; $ii<=$recQ['end']; $ii++)
    {
        if (!in_array($ii, $exclude))
        {
            echo $ii.", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about, adding an additional check to the value using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function:

```
while ($recQ = mysqli_fetch_array($runx))
{
   for($ii=$recQ['start']; $ii<=$recQ['end']; $ii++)
    {
        if (!in_array($ii, $exclude))
        {
            if (!empty($ii)) echo $ii.", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `empty()`? `if ($ii) { ...` would be enough here.

Comment: @Jack, for clarity.. what's the advantage of if($ii) over empty()?

Comment: @jack: to give more clarity when reading the code several months/years from now

Comment: I like this approach. The reason it prints zero when start and end have the same value, is that this loop is always executed at least one time. Making $$i < $rec['end'] could solve it too, but may not work for other cases.

Comment: @ariefbayu If you want more clarity, you could also write `$ii > 0` then; at least you're indicating that it's a number instead of an arbitrary variable.

Comment: -1. If `$req['start']` is zero and `$res['end']` is not, the code would not print the first value.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the execution of the inner loop by using [`continue;`](http://www.php.net/continue) in the main loop:

```
while ($recQ = mysqli_fetch_array($runx))
{
   if ($recQ['start'] == 0 && $recQ['end'] == 0) {
       continue; // skip the rest of the code inside this loop
   }
   for($ii=$recQ['start']; $ii<=$recQ['end']; $ii++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a bit of a different approach:

```
$resulting_set = array();

while( $recQ = mysqli_fetch_array($runx) ){

    $my_set = range( $recQ['start'], $recQ['end'] );

    $resulting_set = array_merge( 
        $resulting_set,
        array_diff( $my_set, $exclude )
    );

}

echo implode( ', ', $resulting_set);
```

The code is a bit easier to read and the result won't have the trailing comma + space you'd get from your version (Assuming you don't need it for some reason).

This is also easier to refactor because you can manipulate the array that contains the output a lot easier than outputting on the fly.

**To remove 0's from the values**, you could just add 0 to your $exclude array.

Comment: I like your approach and what you said about having a comma + space is absolutely right! But this does still keep the zero values in a situation explain in my issue above. Can you suggest a way that this can filter zero vals and avoid them printing? Thanks

Comment: add "0" to your $exclude array? or use array_filter() on your $resulting_set :)